# Finding the Proportion of a specific difference between the average of two vectors

Tags: r, average, difference

I have a question for an assignment I'm doing.
Q:
*"Set the seed at 1, then using a for-loop take a random sample of 5 mice 1,000 times. Save these averages.
What proportion of these 1,000 averages are **more** than 1 gram away from the average of x ?"*

I understand that basically, I need to write a code that says: What percentage of "Nulls" is +or- 1 gram from the average of "x." I'm not really certain how to write that given that this course hasn't given us the information on how to do that yet is asking us to do so. Any help on how to do so?

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleControlsPopulation.csv"
filename <- basename(url)
download(url, destfile=filename)
x <- unlist( read.csv(filename) )
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
nulls<-vector("numeric", n)
for(i in 1:n){
  control <- sample(x, 5)
  nulls[i] <-mean(control)
##I know my last line for this should be something like this
## mean(nulls "+ or - 1")> or < mean(x)
## not certain if they're asking for abs() to be involved.
## is the question asking only for those that are 1 gram MORE than the avg of x?
}
```

Thanks for any help.
Z

Answer (score 0):

I do think that the absolute distance is what they're after here.

Vectors in R are nice in that you can just perform arithmetic operations between a vector and a scalar and it will apply it element-wise, so computing the absolute value of `nulls - mean(x)` is easy. The `abs` function also takes vectors as arguments.

Logical operators (such as `<` and `>`) can also be used in the same way, making it equally simple to compare the result with 1. This will yield a vector of booleans (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) where `TRUE` means the value at that index was indeed greater than 1, but booleans are really just numbers (1 or 0), so you can just sum that vector to find the number of `TRUE` elements.

I don't know what programming level you are on, but I hope this helps without giving the solution away completely (since you said it's for an assignment).